# iOS Sticker Pack Extension is not visible in iMessage if downloaded from the AppStore

Tags: ios, imessage-extension, sticker

I have an regular iOS app where I have added a new Sticker Pack Extension. It's runs fine in Simulator and Phone. Then I submitted it to TestFlight for beta testing. When installing from testflight, the iOS app installs fine along with the Sticker Pack in iMessage.

However, when submitting for Appstore, appstoreconnect shows the host iOS app and the Sticker Pack extension in the build. But, after having the app Ready for Sale in the Appstore, when I install the app from the appstore, the host iOS app installs fine but the Sticker Pack extension in iMessage is totally missing.

Any idea what might be wrong?

I am using Xcode 13 on MacOS Big Sur 11.6

Comment: Did you find a solution? For me, TestFlight doesn’t show the extension